# Inquiries about using Google SDK

Tags: gsutil

I'm Park Sungmin of Bizpring.

We are trying to set up a firewall to use the Google sdk (gsutil, bq) command on the internal server.

I'm trying to set up a firewall based on the domain, which port should I open for which domain?
Please check.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Google APIs operate on HTTPS, so you need to be able to make outbound port 443 connections.